# How do i make it masonry grid based on card content react native

Tags: react-native

```
renderMenuCard = (item) => {
        return (
            <View style={{width: DEVICE_WIDTH/2-moderateScale(22), backgroundColor: '#eee', padding: moderateScale(15), paddingVertical: moderateScale(25), borderRadius: moderateScale(10), marginBottom: moderateScale(15)}}>
                <View style={{height: moderateScale(30), width: moderateScale(30), borderRadius: moderateScale(15), backgroundColor: '#ddd', marginBottom: moderateScale(10)}}></View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent', flexWrap: 'wrap', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <Txt medium>{item.name}</Txt>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }



<FlatList
     contentContainerStyle={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent: 'space- 
     between'}}
     data={this.state.menu_card}
     renderItem={({item}) => (
     this.renderMenuCard(item))}
/>
```

i want that grid to look like masonry
how can i achieve that layout without using 
react-native-masonry library

[the result i got here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD1kC.png)

Comment: Hi @amr to get better help I would recommend that you provide more details via an online playground like https://snack.expo.io/ this way other developers can easier see the whole codebase and not a snippet.

Comment: Hey Amr, Did you find something on this?